# Sorting two Dictionaries and finding the differences in index position of items in the sorted list

Tags: algorithm

I have a challenge in front of me. Let me present the challenge which is perplexing me -

There are two dictionaries say - D1 and D2.
These dictionaries have same keys most of the time but there is no guarantee that it will be always the same. 
The two Dictionaries could be represented as follows -

D1 = {["R1", 0.7], ["R2",0.73], ["R3", 1.5], ["R4", 2.5], ["R5", 0.12], ["R6", 1.9], ["R7", 9.8], ["R8", 6.5], ["R9", 7.2], ["R10", 5.6]};

D2 = {["R1", 0.7], ["R2",0.8], ["R3", 1.5], ["R4", 3.1], ["R5", 0.10], ["R6", 2.0], ["R7", 8.0], ["R8", 1.0], ["R9", 0.0], ["R10", 5.6], ["R11", 6.23]};

Here in these dictionaries, the keys are of string data type and value are of float data type.
Physically they are snapshot of a system in two different times. D1 being older than D2. 
I need to sort these dictionaries independently based on the values in ascending orders. Which when done changes these dictionaries to -

D1 = {["R5", 0.12], ["R1", 0.7], ["R2",0.73], ["R3", 1.5], ["R6", 1.9], ["R4", 2.5], ["R10", 5.6], ["R8", 6.5],  ["R9", 7.2], ["R7", 9.8]};
and
D2 = {["R9", 0.0], ["R5", 0.10], ["R1", 0.7], ["R2",0.8], ["R8", 1.0], ["R3", 1.5], ["R6", 2.0], ["R4", 3.1], ["R10", 5.6], ["R11", 6.23], ["R7", 8.0]};

Here the sorting of elements in the dictionary D1 is taken as reference point. Each element of the D1 is connected with the immediate next one in D1. It is expected to identify the elements in D2 which have broken the sequence as it appears in the reference dictionary D1 after sorting. While determining this addition of elements (i.e. the key not being present in D1 but is present in D2) to D2 and removal of elements (i.e. the key is present in D1 but not in D2) from D1 are ignored. i.e They should not highlighted in the result.

For example, in continuing with the example listed above, the elements which break a sequence in D2 with reference to D1 (ignoring addition and removal) are -

Breakers = {["R9", 0.0],["R8", 1.0]} since, R9 has jumped the sequence from 8th index in D1 sorted dictionary to 0th index in D2 sorted dictionary. Similarly R8 has jumped the sequence from 7th index in D1 sorted dictionary to 4th index in D2 sorted dictionary (all indexes are started from 0).

Note - ["R11", 6.23] is not expected to be in the list of Breakers since it is addition to D2.

Please suggest an algorithm to achieve this optimally, since this operation needs to be performed on data fetched from a database with 3,256,190 records.

Programming language is not a worry, if guided with logic I could take up the task of implementing it in any language.

Comment: is it allowed to trim D2 to the size of D1 (because D2 is larger in this case) before sorting?

Comment: No not allowed. You have to work with D2 as it is.

Comment: will keyname "R1" for the 0th element in D1 always match keyname for 0th element in D2 before sorting?

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is well defined as stated. How do you decide which elements broke the sequence? Let's say D1 is (A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5). If D2 is (A=1,E=5,B=6,C=7,D=8) did E break the sequence or B, C, and D? If D2 is (A=1,B=2,C=3,E=4,D=5) which element broke the sequence? Or if D2 is (C=1,E=2,B=3,D=4,A=5)?

Comment: will keyname "R1" for the 0th element in D1 always match keyname for 0th element in D2 before sorting? – Unfortunately no...

Comment: svinja, for the case where just E came between B and C, it would be E who is to be blamed. This is what is required but I am not sure how to encode this in program. for the last set of elements in D2, it is not something which would be observed in the system, since the system generally behaves in a related way occasional break of sequence. If for some reason D2 has almost every element moved in a random fashion, the D2 is sent for a manual review by design..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this algorithm in C#. It works perfect for you example data. I also did a test with 3000000 totally random values (so a lot of breakers are detected) and it completes in 3.2seconds on my notebook (Intel Core i3 2.1GHz, 64bit).

I first put your data into temporary dictionaries, so I could copy-paste your values, before I put them into the Lists. Of course your application will put them directly in the lists.

```
class Program
{
    struct SingleValue
    {
        public string Key;
        public float Value;
        public SingleValue(string key, float value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}={1}", Key, Value);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<SingleValue> D1 = new List<SingleValue>();
        HashSet<string> D1keys = new HashSet<string>();
        List<SingleValue> D2 = new List<SingleValue>();
#if !LARGETEST
        Dictionary<string, double> D1input = new Dictionary<string, double>() { { "R1", 0.7 }, { "R2", 0.73 }, { "R3", 1.5 }, { "R4", 2.5 }, { "R5", 0.12 }, { "R6", 1.9 }, { "R7", 9.8 }, { "R8", 6.5 }, { "R9", 7.2 }, { "R10", 5.6 } };
        Dictionary<string, double> D2input = new Dictionary<string, double>() { { "R1", 0.7 }, { "R2", 0.8 }, { "R3", 1.5 }, { "R4", 3.1 }, { "R5", 0.10 }, { "R6", 2.0 }, { "R7", 8.0 }, { "R8", 1.0 }, { "R9", 0.0 }, { "R10", 5.6 }, { "R11", 6.23 } };

        // You should directly put you values into this list... I converted them from a Dictionary so I didn't have to type over your input values :)
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in D1input)
        {
            D1.Add(new SingleValue(kvp.Key, (float)kvp.Value));
            D1keys.Add(kvp.Key);
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in D2input)
            D2.Add(new SingleValue(kvp.Key, (float)kvp.Value));
#else
        Random ran = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000000; i++)
        {
            D1.Add(new SingleValue(i.ToString(), (float)ran.NextDouble()));
            D1keys.Add(i.ToString());
            D2.Add(new SingleValue(i.ToString(), (float)ran.NextDouble()));
        }
#endif

        // Sort the lists
        D1.Sort(delegate(SingleValue x, SingleValue y)
        {
            if (y.Value > x.Value)
                return -1;
            else if (y.Value < x.Value)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        });
        D2.Sort(delegate(SingleValue x, SingleValue y)
        {
            if (y.Value > x.Value)
                return -1;
            else if (y.Value < x.Value)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        });

        int start = Environment.TickCount;

        Dictionary<string, float> breakers = new Dictionary<string, float>();
        List<SingleValue> additions = new List<SingleValue>();

        // Walk through D1
        IEnumerator<SingleValue> i1 = D1.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<SingleValue> i2 = D2.GetEnumerator();

        while (i1.MoveNext() && i2.MoveNext())
        {
            while (breakers.ContainsKey(i1.Current.Key))
            {
                if (!i1.MoveNext())
                    break;
            }

            while (i1.Current.Key != i2.Current.Key)
            {
                if (D1keys.Contains(i2.Current.Key))
                    breakers.Add(i2.Current.Key, i2.Current.Value);
                else
                    additions.Add(i2.Current);
                if (!i2.MoveNext())
                    break;
            }
        }

        int duration = Environment.TickCount - start;
        Console.WriteLine("Lookup took {0}ms", duration);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In your code the while loop has both i1 and i2 as iteration condition. This implies both D1 and D2 must be of same size, which is not assured. It could be different and what you have shared is of O(n^4) is that the most optimal we could get? Please suggest..

Comment: They don't have to be the same size. The while loop will just stop if the shortest list is on it's end

Comment: For now in the absence of any other approach, I will mark this as answer.. But I just want to listen from others on any other better approach with minimal loops on the dictionary...

Comment: The code only walks twice through each dictionary. First to sort them, second to search the breakers. If you get the data sorted from the database, you only need to walk through the dictionary once.

Comment: I just measured the sorting of the two lists and for 3000000 items this takes 6.8seconds. So maybe the sorting part can be optimized.

Comment: The problem with this approach is when the D1 sorted is A,B,C,D,E and D2 sorted is B,C,D,E,A - A jumped from the first to the last position, yet this will not be the result. But it is not clear from the OP which elements the "breakers" are.

Comment: @svinja, in that case, the loop would try to match A in D2 and will indeed move the enumerator of D2 to the end of the list, and would stop there... Good catch

Comment: @svinja: To avoid this, you could run the loop again, this time with D1 and D2 swapped, then merging the breakers from both loops.

Comment: @svinja got your point on the jump of A to last in the list. Should it be possible to detect such a jump and declare A as a breaker since, it is the only element jumped with all other elements in sequence? I did read your comment on looping with D1 and D2 swapped but I believe we loose the point of optimizing if we go that way.

Comment: I am not sure would some modification to the algo Levenshtein distance  http://bit.ly/9swKKd of any help here? Any suggestions!!

Comment: Just took a look at Levenshtein algo, it would require you to allocate a 2 dimensional array of 3.000.000 by 3.000.000. Guess what, I'm running out of memory trying to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you could delete stuff from D2 before sorting it would be easy, right? You say you can't delete the data. However, you can make an additional data structure that simulates such deletions (e.g., add a "deleted" bit to the item, or if you can't change its type then make a set of "deleted" items). Then run the simple algorithm, but make sure to ignore items that are "deleted".

Comment: I did not understand what you are saying, can you be little more elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this. As you mentioned Levenshtein distance, I am assuming you want to get those elements by moving whom from their position in D2 to some other position in D2 you will get D1 from D2 in the least number of moves (ignoring elements which don't exist in both sequences).

I wrote a greedy algorithm which may be sufficient for your needs, but it may not necessarily give the optimal result in all cases. I am honestly not sure and may come back to it later (weekend at the earliest) to check the correctness. However, if you really need to do this on sequences of 3 million elements, I believe that no algorithm which does any kind of good job at this will be fast enough, because I can't see an O(n) algorithm which does a good job and can't fail even on some trivial inputs.

This algorithm tries moving each element to its intended position and calculates the sum of errors (how far each element is from its original position) after the move. The element which results in the lowest sum of errors is proclaimed a breaker and moved. This is repeated until the sequence reverts back to D1.

I think it has O(n^3) complexity, although elements sometimes need to be moved multiple times so it could possibly be O(n^4) worst case, I'm not sure, but in 1 million random examples with 50 elements the max number of outer loop runs was 51 (n^4 would mean it can be 2500 and somehow I was lucky in all my million tests). There are just keys, no values. This is because the values are irrelevant in this step so there is no point in storing them.

edit: I wrote a counterexample generator for this and indeed it is not always optimal. The more breakers there are, the less of a chance of an optimal solution. For example, in 1000 elements with 50 randomly moved ones it will usually find a set of 55-60 breakers, when the optimal solution is at most 50.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Breakers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //test case 1
            //List<string> L1 = new List<string> { "R5", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R6", "R4", "R10", "R8", "R9", "R7" };
            //List<string> L2 = new List<string> { "R9", "R5", "R1", "R2", "R8", "R3", "R6", "R4", "R10", "R11", "R7" };
            //GetBreakers<string>(L1, L2);

            //test case 2
            //List<string> L1 = new List<string> { "R5", "R1", "R2", "R3", "R6", "R4", "R10", "R8", "R9", "R7" };
            //List<string> L2 = new List<string> { "R5", "R9", "R1", "R6", "R2", "R3", "R4", "R10", "R8", "R7" };
            //GetBreakers<string>(L1, L2);

            //test case 3
            List<int> L1 = new List<int>();
            List<int> L2 = new List<int>();
            Random r = new Random();
            int n = 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                L1.Add(i);
                L2.Add(i);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // number of random moves, this is the upper bound of the optimal solution
            {
                int a = r.Next() % n;
                int b = r.Next() % n;
                if (a == b)
                {
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                int x = L2[a];
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                L2.RemoveAt(a);
                L2.Insert(b, x);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < L2.Count; i++) Console.Write(L2[i]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            GetBreakers<int>(L1, L2);
        }

        static void GetBreakers<T>(List<T> L1, List<T> L2)
        {
            Dictionary<T, int> Appearances = new Dictionary<T, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < L1.Count; i++) Appearances[L1[i]] = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < L2.Count; i++) if (Appearances.ContainsKey(L2[i])) Appearances[L2[i]] = 2;
            for (int i = L1.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (!(Appearances.ContainsKey(L1[i]) && Appearances[L1[i]] == 2)) L1.RemoveAt(i);
            for (int i = L2.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (!(Appearances.ContainsKey(L2[i]) && Appearances[L2[i]] == 2)) L2.RemoveAt(i);
            Dictionary<T, int> IndInL1 = new Dictionary<T, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < L1.Count; i++) IndInL1[L1[i]] = i;

            Dictionary<T, int> Breakers = new Dictionary<T, int>();

            int steps = 0;
            int me = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                steps++;
                int minError = int.MaxValue;
                int minErrorIndex = -1;

                for (int from = 0; from < L2.Count; from++)
                {
                    T x = L2[from];
                    int to = IndInL1[x];
                    if (from == to) continue;

                    L2.RemoveAt(from);
                    L2.Insert(to, x);

                    int error = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < L2.Count; i++)
                        error += Math.Abs((i - IndInL1[L2[i]]));

                    L2.RemoveAt(to);
                    L2.Insert(from, x);

                    if (error < minError)
                    {
                        minError = error;
                        minErrorIndex = from;
                    }
                }

                if (minErrorIndex == -1) break;

                T breaker = L2[minErrorIndex];
                int breakerOriginalPosition = IndInL1[breaker];

                L2.RemoveAt(minErrorIndex);
                L2.Insert(breakerOriginalPosition, breaker);

                Breakers[breaker] = 1;

                me = minError;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Breakers: " + Breakers.Count + " Steps: " + steps);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<T, int> p in Breakers)
                Console.WriteLine(p.Key);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```